# Kotlin reflection to generate one class from class similar with similar properties

Tags: android, reflection, kotlin

This code is intended to generate a class (domain) from a class with class with similar/identical properties (api). Motivation is to speed development time when using clean architecture.

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone
import javax.inject.Inject
import kotlin.reflect.KClass
import kotlin.reflect.KParameter
import kotlin.reflect.full.declaredMemberProperties
import kotlin.reflect.full.findAnnotation

class DomainApiReflectionAdapter<DOMAIN : Any, API : Any> constructor(
        val clazz: KClass<DOMAIN>
) {

    fun fromApi(apiModel: API): DOMAIN {
        return apiToDomain(apiModel, clazz)
    }

    inline fun <API : Any, DOMAIN : Any> apiToDomain(apiModel: API, clazz: KClass<DOMAIN>): DOMAIN {
        val factory = Factory(clazz)
        val apiProperties = toPropMap(apiModel)
        val constructorMap = mutableMapOf<KParameter, Any?>()
        for (param in factory.params) {
            param.findAnnotation<AdapterValues>()?.let {
                val iclass = param.type.classifier as KClass<*>
                println(iclass)
                constructorMap[param] = innerFactory.simpleConstruct(apiProperties)
            } ?: {
                if (param.name in apiProperties) {
                    constructorMap[param] = when {
                        param.type.classifier == List::class -> {
                            val itype = param.type.arguments[0].type!!.classifier as KClass<*>
                            (apiProperties[param.name] as List<*>).map {
                                it?.toDomain(itype)
                            }
                        }
                        param.type.classifier == DateTime::class -> DateTime(apiProperties[param.name] as Long, DateTimeZone.forID("UTC"))
                        else -> apiProperties[param.name]
                    }
                }
            }()
        }

        return factory.construct(constructorMap)
    }

    fun <K : Any> toPropMap(model: K): Map<String, Any?> {
        return model.javaClass.kotlin.declaredMemberProperties
                .map { prop ->
                    prop.name to prop.get(model)
                }.toMap()
    }

    companion object {
        inline fun <reified DOMAIN : Any, API : Any> instance(): DomainApiReflectionAdapter<DOMAIN, API> {
            return DomainApiReflectionAdapter(DOMAIN::class)
        }
    }

    inner class Factory<DOMAIN : Any>(clazz: KClass<DOMAIN>) {
        private val constructor = clazz.constructors.first()
        val params = constructor.parameters

        fun construct(map: Map<KParameter, Any?>): DOMAIN {
            return constructor.callBy(map)
        }

        fun simpleConstruct(apiProperties: Map<String, Any?>): DOMAIN {
            val innerMap = mutableMapOf<KParameter, Any?>()
            for (ip in params) {
                innerMap[ip] = apiProperties[ip.name]
            }
            return construct(innerMap)
        }
    }
}

fun <DOMAIN : Any, API : Any> API.toDomain(clazz: KClass<DOMAIN>): DOMAIN {
    val adapter = DomainApiReflectionAdapter<DOMAIN, API>(clazz)
    return adapter.fromApi(this)
}

abstract class Adapter<A, B> : (B) -> A

@Target(AnnotationTarget.VALUE_PARAMETER)
annotation class AdapterClass()

@Target(AnnotationTarget.VALUE_PARAMETER)
annotation class AdapterValues(val parameters: Array<String>)
```

Answer (score 4):

### inline functions

inline function are great when:

- You want to surround a lambda with a little code
- You want to use [reified types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters).

They are not great when you have a large function, as every call to that function will be replaced with the body of the function.

Therefor, inlining apiToDomain seams the wrong choice.
You have another function: API.toDomain.

#### [associate](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/associate.html)

I found the following in your code:
    map{ it.a to it.b }.toMap()

This can replaced by:

```
associate{ it.a to it.b }
```

(it can be used if you have one parameter)

#### associateWith

In kotlin 1.3, you can use associateWith for `simpleConstruct`:

```
val map = listOf(1,2,3).associateWith{ it.toString }
println(map) // [1:"1", 2:"2", 3:"3"]
```

#### when

your when looks like

```
when {
    param.type.classifier == List::class -> 
    param.type.classifier == DateTime::class -> 
    else ->
}
```

this can be simplified to:

```
when(param.type.classifier) {
    List::class -> 
    DateTime::class -> 
    else ->
}
```

#### run

in your function, you use {...}(). run{} does exactly the same, but you can't forget to invoke it. This is however a personal choice.

#### function bodies

I personnaly don't like functions where the body starts with return:

```
fun fromApi(apiModel: API): DOMAIN {
    return apiToDomain(apiModel, clazz)
}
```

you can rewrite this as:

```
fun fromApi(apiModel: API): DOMAIN = apiToDomain(apiModel, clazz)
```

or even like:

```
fun fromApi(apiModel: API) = apiToDomain(apiModel, clazz)
```

### typealias

I dont know exactly the purpose of

```
abstract class Adapter<A, B> : (B) -> A
```

but maybe you can use a [typealias](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-aliases.html)?

```
typealias Adapter<A, B> = (B) -> A
```

**constructing**

I thing you forgot a keyword in front of your constructor? As you wrote it out and you have a companion-object that creates a type of your class...
Ps. If you want to construct in your companion-object, but it should look like a constructor-call, you can use `operator fun invoke(...)`

Hope this helps a bit